# Printing http chunks and their arrival time

Tags: google-chrome, http, curl, chunked-encoding, chunked

Is there any way to print http chunks and their arrival time ? Using curl or any other visualization tool? any quick way to write this in javascript?

I found a tool called chunk scatter http://scatter.cowchimp.com/ but it is not working for https url.

Answer (score 12):

With curl, you can pass the `--raw` option which will make curl not "decode" the transfer encoding and instead pass that on to the output, so then you can write your own "decoder" that's output times for each new chunk it finds.